# Parallel rays hitting a parabolic mirror at an angle

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

I was thinking about parallel rays hitting a mirror that has a parabolic horisontal cross-section and a linear (straight) vertical cross-section. I can't understand what would happen if the rays came in at an angle to the horizontal plane, but still parallel to the vertical plane defined by the normal of the mirror at it's centre and the vertical axis.

Comment: "I don't understand what would happen" is not a question. What kind of response are you expecting? A derivation of the path? A description of where foci might be?

Comment: A description of where foci might be is what I am looking for, or if there even is a foci

Comment: This question definitely needs a figure.